# Adding up values around a specific point in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So I have a 2D array which is filled with 1's and 0's. I want to check the neighbours of a specific index in the array, and add their values up.

The first and last rows and columns (aka the 'bordering' values) are special cases as they are not completely surrounded with neighbouring values which means I have to put lots of conditionals to take them into account.

If I only do the first if statement, I get the problem of arrayIndexOutOfBounds. Which makes sense to me as its trying to go to position integerGeneration[-1][-1], for example.

What I have done below works, but its really ugly and I feel there is a "neater" approach to this.

Is there a better way than doing all the special cases on the outer borders of the array in their own else if statements?

```
// checks the inside box
if ((x > 0 & x < rows - 1) & (y > 0 & y < columns - 1)) {
    for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++) {
        for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
// checks the top edge
} else if (x == 0 & y < columns - 1 & y > 0) {
    for (int i = x; i < x + 2; i++) {
        for (int j = (y - 1); j < y + 2; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
// checks the left edge
} else if (y == 0 & x < rows - 1 & x > 0) {
    for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++) {
        for (int j = y; j < y + 2; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
// checks the top left corner
} else if (x == 0 & y == 0) {
    for (int i = x; i < x + 2; i++) {
        for (int j = y; j < y + 2; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
// checks the bottom edge
} else if (x == rows - 1 & y < columns - 1 & y > 0) {
    for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
// checks the right edge
} else if (y == columns - 1 & x < rows - 1 & x > 0) {
    for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++) {
        for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 1; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
// checks the bottom right corner
} else if (y == columns - 1 & x == rows - 1) {
    for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 1; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
// checks the top right corner
} else if (x == 0 & y == columns - 1) {
    for (int i = x; i < x + 2; i++) {
        for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 1; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
// checks the bottom left corner
} else if (x == rows - 1 & y == 0) {
    for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = y; j < y + 2; j++) {
            filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
        }
    }
    filled = filled - integerGeneration[x][y];
    return filled;
} else {
    System.out.println("Error, point out of bounds");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code duplication. Why don't you just have the loops iterate over the "surrounding" elements and check the relevant index before trying to access (e.g.: `if(x < 0) continue;`)

Comment: Also this might be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @UnholySheep Oh, oops. Do you mean something like this?
 public static int neighbours(int x, int y) {         // get the number of filled neighbours
  int filled = 0;

  for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++) {
   for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++) {
    if ((i < 0 | i >= rows) | (j < 0 | j >= columns) | (i == x & j == y))
     continue;
    else
     filled += integerGeneration[i][j];
   }
  }
  return filled;
 }

Comment: oh wow, and im not allowed to edit that D:
` for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++) {
  for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++) {
   if ((i < 0 | i >= rows) | (j < 0 | j >= columns) | (i == x & j == y))
    continue;
   else
    filled += integerGeneration[i][j];
  }
 }
 return filled;`

Comment: diddnt help much xD

Comment: Apart from you using the bitwise or `|` instead of the logical or `||` (and bitwise and instead of logical and) it does look ok (at first glance, you will obviously have to test it to make sure it does behave correctly)

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you very much! Works perfectly and reduced the class by about 100 lines xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
filled = 0;
for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++) {
    for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= rows || j < 0 || j >= columns || i == x || j == y)
            continue;
        filled = integerGeneration[i][j] + filled;
    }
}
return filled;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be i==x && j==y?

Comment: yeah sorry it was typo

Comment: no worries, was just checking to make sure I understood that correctly :P Thank you very much!

Comment: if(i<0 || i>=rows || j<0 || j>=columns || (i==x &&  j==y))

Comment: welcome and you can also upvote the answer if you are satisfied

Comment: yeah it gets recorded but not shown because im new to stackoverflow ^^ dont have enough reputation yet.